# eclipselink 2.5.2 Joincolumn naming convention

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

when I use Eclipse JPA tools with Eclipselink 2.5.2 to generate the entity from the database :

- 2 tables **pr_user** and **pr**
- table **pr** has 2 columns **requested_by** and **prepared_by**
- table **pr_user** has 1 column **id** which is the primary key
- **pr_user.id** is the foreign key of **pr.requested_by** and **pr.prepared_by**

What I expect of the entity class Pr is that

```
private PrUser requestedBy;
private PrUser preparedBy;
```

But what I have is that

```
private PrUser prUser1;
private PrUser prUser2;
```

Please help if I need any configurations Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you generate them? Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes. by Eclipse JPA Tools

Comment: There you can edit the names of the reference it is creating. So I don't understand your problem.